# SendGrid API Receive response 0 if we add attachments to the message, but received the mail (all are delivered)

Tags: attachment, sendgrid-api-v3

By using the code below while sending the mail received response as 0, with out attachments I received the response as accepted. why I received 0, but we received mail including the attachments?

```
var client = new SendGridClient(APIKEYVALUE);
var msg = new SendGridMessage()
{
    From = new EmailAddress(FromEmail),
    Subject = Subject,
    PlainTextContent = "",
    HtmlContent = MailBody
   
};
```

Already attachments are attached to the attachment list class

```
msg.AddAttachments(objAttachmentsList.Select(i => new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Attachment
{
    Content = i.Content,
    Filename =i.Filename,
    Type = i.Type,
    Disposition = i.Disposition
}));
if (DeliveryEmail.Split(',').Count() > 1)
    msg.AddTos(DeliveryEmail.Split(',').Select(i => new EmailAddress(i)).ToList());
else
    msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(DeliveryEmail));

if (BCCEmail.Length > 0)
{
    if (BCCEmail.Split(',').Count() > 1)
    msg.AddBccs(BCCEmail.Split(',').Select(i => new EmailAddress(i)).ToList());
    else
    msg.AddBcc(BCCEmail);
}
if (CCEmail.Length > 0)
{
    if (CCEmail.Split(',').Count() > 1)
    msg.AddCcs(CCEmail.Split(',').Select(i => new EmailAddress(i)).ToList());
    else
    msg.AddCc(CCEmail);
}
if (ReplyToEmail.Length > 0)
{
    if (ReplyToEmail.Split(',').Count() > 1)
    msg.AddReplyTos(ReplyToEmail.Split(',').Select(i => new EmailAddress(i)).ToList());
    else
    msg.AddReplyTo(ReplyToEmail);
}
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Attachments added to the list

```
public void AddMailAttachments(string FilePath)
{           
    SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Attachment objattachment = new SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.Attachment {
        Content = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)),
        Filename = Path.GetFileName(FilePath),
        Type = "application/octet-stream",
        Disposition = "attachment"
    };
    objAttachmentsList.Add(objattachment);
}
```

AS per the send grid they mentioned response.statuscode is "Accepted" but we received 0
which I found by writing the log `SendresponseToText(response.StatusCode.ToString())`. this method will write every thing in to the text file mentioned.
There it just writes 0.